# How to setup python 3 from virtual environment as the default python for Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtualenv, digital-ocean

I have a droplet from DigitalOcean. It runs Ubuntu 16.04. By default, it is using Python2.

I have a website created with Django. I want to setup a virtual env and run python 3 in the virtual environment. The HTTP server in the droplet is NGINX.

How can I let the droplet pick up the python 3 in the virtual environment as the python for my Django project?

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

s   `virtualenv -p python3 envname` or `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 <venv-name>` that's going to create a virtualenv with python3, tell me if I misunderstood the question

Comment: Thank for the response. I understand how to create a virtual environment. But I don't know how to make the VPS use the python from this virtual environment to working with Django.

Comment: By default will use the specific python